# Wine: Prefix creation exited with error

Tags: macos, wine

I'm trying to get wine/winebottler to work on my mac. I've got OS X El Capitan 10.11.5. But whenever I try to run an .exe file, I'm getting the following error: "Prefix creation exited with error" and the following log:

```
###BOTTLING### customprefix.sh
###BOTTLING### Gathering debug Info...

Versions
OS...........................: darwin15
Wine.........................: 1.4.1
WineBottler..................: 1.4.1

Environment
PWD..........................: '/Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin'
PATH.........................: /usr/gnu/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:.
WINEPATH.....................: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH..............: 
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH...: 
FONTCONFIG_FILE..............: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/etc/fonts/fonts.conf
DIPSPLAY.....................: /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.8YDmM9MQvn/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
SILENT.......................: 
http_proxy...................: 
https_proxy..................: 
ftp_proxy....................: 
socks5_proxy.................: 

Hardware:

    Hardware Overview:

      Model Name: MacBook Air
      Model Identifier: MacBookAir6,1
      Processor Name: Intel Core i5
      Processor Speed: 1,4 GHz
      Number of Processors: 1
      Total Number of Cores: 2
      L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
      L3 Cache: 3 MB
      Memory: 8 GB
      Boot ROM Version: MBA61.0099.B22
      SMC Version (system): 2.12f143
      Serial Number (system): C02NK02MG5RK
      Hardware UUID: DFAA0049-4DD3-596A-8F15-F937EBF89364

###BOTTLING### Turn on Coreaudio...
wine: created the configuration directory '/Users/janni/Wine Files'
Wine cannot find the FreeType font library.  To enable Wine to
use TrueType fonts please install a version of FreeType greater than
or equal to 2.0.5.
Wine cannot find the FreeType font library.  To enable Wine to
use TrueType fonts please install a version of FreeType greater than
or equal to 2.0.5.
err:x11drv:process_attach failed to load libX11.6.dylib: dlopen(libX11.6.dylib, 10): image not found
err:x11drv:process_attach failed to load libX11.6.dylib: dlopen(libX11.6.dylib, 10): image not found
err:x11drv:process_attach failed to load libX11.6.dylib: dlopen(libX11.6.dylib, 10): image not found
err:x11drv:process_attach failed to load libX11.6.dylib: dlopen(libX11.6.dylib, 10): image not found
Wine cannot find the FreeType font library.  To enable Wine to
use TrueType fonts please install a version of FreeType greater than
or equal to 2.0.5.
Wine cannot find the FreeType font library.  To enable Wine to
use TrueType fonts please install a version of FreeType greater than
or equal to 2.0.5.
err:x11drv:process_attach failed to load libX11.6.dylib: dlopen(libX11.6.dylib, 10): image not found
err:x11drv:process_attach failed to load libX11.6.dylib: dlopen(libX11.6.dylib, 10): image not found
err:x11drv:process_attach failed to load libX11.6.dylib: dlopen(libX11.6.dylib, 10): image not found
err:x11drv:process_attach failed to load libX11.6.dylib: dlopen(libX11.6.dylib, 10): image not found
Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
err:appbar:initialize_appbar Could not create appbar message window
Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
err:systray:initialize_systray Could not create tray window
Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
err:psdrv:PSDRV_PPDGetNextTuple Line too long.
err:psdrv:PSDRV_PPDGetNextTuple Line too long.
err:psdrv:PSDRV_PPDGetNextTuple Line too long.
err:psdrv:PSDRV_PPDGetNextTuple Line too long.
fixme:psdrv:PSDRV_UpdateDevCaps Can't find page
err:rundll32:wWinMain Unable to load L"setupapi"
wine: configuration in '/Users/janni/Wine Files' has been updated.
###BOTTLING### Sandboxing...
### LOG ### Command 'find /Users/janni/Wine Files/drive_c/users/janni -name * -type l -exec sh -c rm "{}"; mkdir -p "{}" ;' returned status 1.

###ERROR### Command 'find /Users/janni/Wine Files/drive_c/users/janni -name * -type l -exec sh -c rm "{}"; mkdir -p "{}" ;' returned status 1.
find: /Users/janni/Wine Files/drive_c/users/janni: No such file or directory
Task returned with status 15.
```

It seems, other people habe got this problem too, but google was not able to give me any usable solution.

Comment: It has something to do with `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: It should be set to something like `/Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/lib`, but it's not set to anything.

Comment: I have no idea why.